# Count Words from TextBox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count

I have code that counts characters in a TextBox.

```
Sub CountCharFromTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lTxtBoxWords As Long
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each shp In wks.Shapes
            If TypeName(shp) <> "GroupObject" Then
                lTxtBoxWords = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Count
            End If
        Next shp
    Next wks
    MsgBox lTxtBoxWords
End Sub
```

How can I count words from Textboxes?

I can't find any similar Property for TextFrame. TextFrame2 doesnt work.

Comment: So, the TextBox has a string, correct? Could you perhaps count the spaces in there, and use that number +1 ?

Comment: Your post makes it rather unclear as to whether you actually want to count _words_ or _characters_ ...

Comment: My goal is count words from TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David. He gave me the right inspiration. The code is finally found. Thanks for me and David. Now I can share with others too:

```
    Sub CountWordsFromTextBox()

        Dim shp As Shape
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Dim lTxtBoxWords As String
        theNumWords = 0
            For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                For Each shp In wks.Shapes
                    If TypeName(shp) <> "GroupObject" And shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text <> "" Then
                        lTxtBoxWords = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
                        theNumWords = theNumWords + Len(Trim(lTxtBoxWords)) - Len(Replace(Trim(lTxtBoxWords), " ", "")) + 1
                    End If
                Next shp
                Next wks
                MsgBox theNumWords
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Function countWords(ByVal sentence As String) As Integer
    countWords = UBound(Split(sentence, " ")) + 1
End Function
```

Explanation:

The Split() function returns an array of strings split on a delimiter you specify.  For example, split("Carl is awesome"," ") would split on " " (a space) and return:
["Carl", "is", "awesome"].  The indices of this array are 0-2.

Ubound() returns the index of the last element in an array.  Since arrays from split() start at 0, we need to add 1 to the result of ubound().

The function CountWords() takes a string and returns the number of spaces+1, which is almost certainly the number of words.  You might consider checking the length of elements returned by split() to catch 0-length "words", i.e. double spaces or leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Hi. Carl..But how to do it in the TextBox? How to embed it in the shape?

Comment: I haven't worked with the TextFrame object much, but you could do something like this:
lTxtBoxWords = countWords(shp.TextFrame.Characters)

Comment: i supplemented this function, but it doesnt work for shapes: my line with this function for my macro was following - countWords(shp.TextFrame) and no luck.

Comment: also  countWords(shp.TextFrame.Characters) doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
Sub CountCharFromTextBoxV2()
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(shp.Name)).Select
        theString = Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
        theNumWords = Len(Trim(theString)) - Len(Replace(Trim(theString), " ", "")) + 1
        MsgBox "TextBox Name: " & shp.Name & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Number of words: " & theNumWords
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Although your code doesnt sum up all textbox's words count and it pops out message boxes from each text box separately i adapt your code part to my first code below. Thank you to find the right approach.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get that from your initial question. I thought the question and the code sample suggested you were just summing one box at a time. In fact, it seems everyone else read it like that, too. Don't worry I'm just being cheeky, vying for extra points :-). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If words are character strings separated by a space, then you can count words in any string like:

```
Sub WordCount()
    Dim s As String

    s = "klaatu barada nikto"
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MsgBox UBound(Split(.Trim(s), " ")) + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Here *Trim()* is used to remove any extraneous spaces

**EDIT#1:**

Here is how I would apply this to a TextBox.  First create the TextBox:

```
Sub BoxMaker()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 217.5, 51#, _
        482.25, 278.25).Select
    Selection.Name = "SPLASH"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Please Wait for Macro"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=21).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 36
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

and here is how I would count the words in that TextBox:

```
Sub WordCounter2()
    Dim s As String
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SPLASH").Select
    s = Selection.Characters.Text
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MsgBox UBound(Split(.Trim(s), " ")) + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But how to do it in the TextBox? This is general calculation in the cells, but i have the textboxes not cells

Comment: @spriteup  See my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: Nice try. Thanks. But there is constant string for textbox name ("SPLASH"). And that is not i am looking for. David showed me better way and inspiring by his method I finally found better solution. See below.

Comment: @spriteup You should reconsider. Gary's Student's answer is the best one here. Think a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

**Tested**

```
Sub CountCharFromTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lTxtBoxWords As Long
    Dim lTxtBoxWordsnew As Long
        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each shp In wks.Shapes
                If TypeName(shp) <> "GroupObject" Then
                    lTxtBoxWords = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Count
                    lTxtBoxWordsnew = getwordscount(shp.TextFrame.Characters.text)
                End If
            Next shp
        Next wks
        MsgBox lTxtBoxWordsnew
End Sub


Private Function getwordscount(text As String)
    getwordscount = Len(text) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(text, " ", "")) + 1
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karthick it is another solution. But I have already created it. Below I added my last comment. 

About your code : create another TextBox and launch again. What do you see? :) Modify this line and insert lTxtBoxWordsnew = 0 after last dim.
lTxtBoxWordsnew = lTxtBoxWordsnew  + getwordscount(shp.TextFrame.Characters.text)

Answer (score 0):

Great code! Is it possible to use this in PowerPoint?

```
Sub CountWordsFromTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lTxtBoxWords As String
    theNumWords = 0
        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each shp In wks.Shapes
                If TypeName(shp) <> "GroupObject" And shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text <> "" Then
                    lTxtBoxWords = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
                    theNumWords = theNumWords + Len(Trim(lTxtBoxWords)) - Len(Replace(Trim(lTxtBoxWords), " ", "")) + 1
                End If
            Next shp
            Next wks
            MsgBox theNumWords
    End Sub
```